# Ctags doesn't display line number with iterm2

Tags: macos, ctags, cscope, iterm, iterm2

I switched to iterm2 on my Mac last week. However I found there was an issue when I used cscope with iterm2. The following is the screenshot of the good and bad case.

Good case: Use cscope with Mac default terminal
[image: Cscope with the same file using Mac default terminal]

Bad Case: Use cscope with iterm2 terminal
[image: Cscope using iterm2]

In the bad case, there is no file and line numbers. I am using OSX 10.10.2. Could anyone tell me what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to tweak you color settings in iTerm. In your current settings you probably have `Bold` set to white.

Go to `Preferences`->`Profiles`. Choose the profile you want to adjust and go to `Colors` tab. Choose one of the presets or set each color individually.